# canvas.translate makes duplicate bitmap

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-canvas

I use this code to put my bitmap image at a new position (x,y), but **canvas.translate**

makes my bitmap duplicate. What's wrong with this code?

```
  val height: Int = bitmapImage.height
  val width: Int = bitmapImage.width      

      
  val mat = Matrix()
  mat.setScale(w/ width, h/ height)

  canvas.translate(startX, startY) //100,300
  canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapImage, mat, null)
```

Comment: You might be reusing an already used canvas

Comment: share whole class